# Package name containing hyphen

Tags: go, go-playground

I am having some trouble understanding that why my code complains when I have hyphen in package.
e.g. if I have a package name foo-bar and I declare that package name

```
package foo-bar

foo-bar/config.go:1:13: expected ';', found '-'
```

Then why does the Go compiler complain? Does it mean we should not use hyphens in go package names?

Since there are many repo that has use hyphen in package name, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: By convention, packages are given lower case, single-word names; there should be no need for underscores or mixedCaps. [Ref](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names)

Comment: "Does it mean we should not use hyphens in go package names?" It doesn't mean you should not, it means you must not. Dead simple.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

We can see [from the Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_clause) that a package name must be a valid identifier:

> PackageName    = identifier .

We can further [read](https://golang.org/ref/spec#identifier) that a valid identifier is defined as:

> identifier = letter { letter | unicode_digit } .

So package names may contain only letters and digits.  `-` characters are not permitted.

We can [further read](https://golang.org/ref/spec#letter) that as a bit of a special case, the underscore character (`_`) is defined as a letter, for the purpose of Go identifiers:

> The underscore character _ (U+005F) is considered a letter.

So you may substitute `-` with `_` for your package name if you wish.

However, please consider *not* doing so, as it's considered non-idiomatic.  For advice on package naming in Go, please read the section of [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) on [package names](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names), or read The Go Blog's post on [Package Names](https://blog.golang.org/package-names).

Answer (score 13):

from [Go Package Name blog post](https://blog.golang.org/package-names):

> The style of names typical of another language might not be idiomatic in a Go program. Here are two examples of names that might be good style in other languages but do not fit well in Go:
>
> - computeServiceClient
> - priority_queue

If your package address has `-` in name, your can set your package name  with an underline.

Example:

package file address : some/where/foo-bar/config.go

```
package foo_bar

// your codes
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not directly related, for some reason when creating a project layout I keep trying to search whether there are rules or guidelines regarding the naming of the "path" part of go modules. I found little other than "There are also several [lexical restrictions](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-ident) on characters allowed in module paths" in [Go Modules Reference](https://golang.org/ref/mod). I guess I can use hyphens freely when organizing the directory structure.